# JQuery return false not stopping from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JQuery function:

```
function CheckRequired(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    var emptyElements = $form.find('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value === ''
    });

    if(emptyElements.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();

        emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect").attr('title', 'This field is required');

        //alert(emptyElements.attr("id"));
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");

        return false;
    }
}
```

i call this function using another function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', CheckRequired);
});
```

so it will be called on ALL forms

It checks for form elements with a class of `required`

i then have this in PHP:

```
if($_POST) {

}
```

to check for posted forms (this is on each page)

however the `return false` is not stopping the form from being posted

**UPDATE:**

the form submit button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm('#form1', '<?php echo $Settings_PathName; ?>/<?php echo $Settings_PagesPath; ?>/companies/customers/company.php?customer=<?php echo $customer["sequence"]; ?>', '.EditCustomer');" class="btn btn-default" />
```

the function `SubmitForm` is:

```
function SubmitForm(form, postaction, div_name) {
    CheckRequired();

    $(form).submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        //$('#LoadingDiv').show();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(postaction, data)
        .success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            //$('#LoadingDiv').hide();
            $( div_name ).html(result);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        })
        .error(function(){
            $( div_name ).html('Error Loading Page');
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

            console.log('Error loading page');
            console.log(result);
        })
        return false;
    });
}
```

so the form is on `company.php` which is being loaded from `customers.php`

`customers.php` has this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.EditCustomer').load("<?php echo $Settings_PathName;?>/<?php echo $Settings_PagesPath; ?>/companies/customers/company.php?customer=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>");
});
```

so the form is submitted without having to refresh the main page, it just re-loads using jquery

Comment: CheckRequired is being called from my PHP page

Comment: sorry about that - see my update, first of all i misunderstood you :)

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` should be enough to stop the `submit` from proceeding. That `return` is not needed. Oddly your code looks correct for the way you are using it. I assume the alert *is* firing?

Comment: i am seeing the alert fine but as soon as that is dismissed it continues to execute the php code inside if($_POST) { }

Comment: @charlie can you confirm that you don't have any errors in the browser console.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Any error would stop the code working so submits would proceed.

Comment: no there are no other errors

Comment: Your code, *as shown*, works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qmhfnstz/ As you can see you do not need the `return false` as you have `preventDefault()`. Your problem lays elsewhere. Have you got unobtrusive validation enabled as well, as that intercepts `submit` too?

Comment: sorry - please check my update. i missed this part of the code out

Comment: In SubmitForm your CheckRequired without parameter Event

Comment: That new part is the cause of the problem. don't combine inline event handlers with jQuery handlers. just use jQuery event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you call it like:

```
$('form').submit(CheckRequired);
```

or you can see:

`$(this)` in your function is not what you think, it is window object. You have to pass the context in your function call:

```
function CheckRequired(event, el) {
    var $form = $(el); // <---pass the context element here

    var emptyElements = $form.find('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value.trim() === ''; //<-----should trim the value.
    });

    if(emptyElements.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();

        emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect").attr('title', 'This field is required');

        //alert(emptyElements.attr("id"));
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");
        // return false; // it is not needed as you are using event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

then you can call it like:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    CheckRequired(this);
});
```

Comment: Now the calling code has been shown, you can see it already does what you suggest and has the correct context for `this` (the form submitted)

Comment: That is what I am thinking

Answer (score 0):

That last bit you added is your problem. You are actually connecting the `submit` event handler only after a `click` event! That also does not allow for keyboard submission of the form.

Remove the `onclick` handler on the `submit` button and use a jQuery event handler *on the form* instead.

e.g.

Html:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

If you need specific "extra" information from each form (a name etc), you can inject them as data- attributes on the form and fetch them using `.data()` on the jQuery form object.

### Notes:

- You should be able to fetch the div etc relative to the clicked form instead of passing it. *To give a precise example would require more of your HTML.*

Comment: so where do i call the SubmitForm function ?

Comment: You already are, in your other piece of code. So it would be similar. If you can show an example of your page/form's output HTML (e.g. as saved from a browser, not the PHP source) I can mock it up properly.

Comment: well the code i can see from the source page is: <div class="EditCustomer"></div>
    
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.EditCustomer').load("/pages/companies/customers/company.php?customer=340");
  
  $('.tab').each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function(){
    $('.EditCustomer').load("/pages/companies/customers/" + $(this).attr('href') + "?customer=340");
   });
  });
 }); 
    </script>

Comment: Okay... different approach as the page content appears to be loaded dynamically. Use the Chrome browser F12 tools - DOM inspector and copy the HTML of the body element, Put that into your question. Thanks.